# Alternative for find() manipulation of an object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This is my origin data/param:

```
const reference = ["gYDJWsfSHFBzoGjya", "hp9v53uQqQPRXSYAi"] // expected new reference value
const elementID = "XyLChbksZjenyEHqL" // ID of the array object which should be updated

const data = {
  getContent: {
    content: [
      { _id: "XyLChbksZjenyEHqL", reference: ['hp9v53uQqQPRXSYAi'] },
      // some more objects here
    ]
  }
}
```

Now I need to set the reference value of the array object with the specific id.

```
const result = {
  getContent: {
    content: [
      { _id: "XyLChbksZjenyEHqL", reference: ["gYDJWsfSHFBzoGjya", "hp9v53uQqQPRXSYAi"] },
      // some more objects here
    ]
  }
}
```

I did it this way:

```
data.getContent.content
  .find(({ _id }) => _id === elementID).reference = reference
```

But as IE11 is not supporting find(), I'm asking if there is an alternative way to get this done.
I don't want to use a polyfill for that simple thing.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with using polyfills whenever their function's utility results in clearer, more readable code than the alternative, even if it seems trivial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

You can use a forEach loop, and match all the object ids with element id and update the reference of the object whose element id matches with the object id.

> Please Note-
>   forEach is supported in IE9 or greater version, if your are using previous version please use simple for loop. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
const reference = ["gYDJWsfSHFBzoGjya", "hp9v53uQqQPRXSYAi"] ;
const elementID = "XyLChbksZjenyEHqL" ;

const data = {
  getContent: {
    content: [
      { _id: "XyLChbksZjenyEHqL", reference: ['hp9v53uQqQPRXSYAi'] },
      // some more objects here
    ]
  }
};
data.getContent.content.forEach(function(o){
  if(o._id === elementID){
      o.reference = reference;
   }
});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forEach`:

```
data.getContent.content.forEach((element)=>{
    if (element.id === elementID){
         element.reference = reference;
    }
});
```

It works in a similar way. You pass in a `callback` to the `forEach` function, and it executes that callback on every element of the array.

Then, you check if the current element being processed has the same `id` as given by the `elementID`.

If it is, then you set the `reference` of that particular element to whatever you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `for loop`

```js
const reference = ["gYDJWsfSHFBzoGjya", "hp9v53uQqQPRXSYAi"];
let elementID = "XyLChbksZjenyEHqL";
const result = {
  getContent: {
    content: [
      { _id: "XyLChbksZjenyEHqL", reference: ["gYDJWsfSHFBzoGjya", "hp9v53uQqQPRXSYAi"] },
      // some more objects here
    ]
  }
}

let obj;
for (let i = 0; i < result.getContent.content.length; i++) {
  if(result.getContent.content[i]._id === elementID) {
    obj = result.getContent.content[i];
    break;
  }
}
if(obj) obj.reference= reference;
console.log(result)
```

You can also update the object in the loop itself

```js
const reference = ["gYDJWsfSHFBzoGjya", "hp9v53uQqQPRXSYAi"];
let elementID = "XyLChbksZjenyEHqL";
const result = {
  getContent: {
    content: [
      { _id: "XyLChbksZjenyEHqL", reference: ["gYDJWsfSHFBzoGjya", "hp9v53uQqQPRXSYAi"] },
   ]
  }
};

for (let i = 0; i < result.getContent.content.length; i++) {
  if(result.getContent.content[i]._id === elementID) {
    result.getContent.content[i].reference = reference;
    break;
  }
}
console.log(result)
```

Or you can create a Polyfill for `Array.find` as given on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 0):

The following `find()` `function` `returns` the first match from an `array` for a given `predicate`.

See [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) and [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) for more info.

A `JS transpiler` such as [`Babel`](https://babeljs.io/) might also be worth investigating.

```js
// Input.
const input = [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}, {id:4}, {id:5, y:'five'}]

// Find.
function find(array, predicate) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i ++) {
    var x = array[i];
    if (predicate(x)) {
      return x;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

// Proof.
console.log(find(input, x => x.id === 5)) // {id: 5, y: 'five'}
console.log(find(input, x => x.id === 10)) // false
```